# How to do two function in a drop down list box

Tags: php, html

Here is my doubt in brief. I am having a drop down box with some values like Artist, Song, Album, Composer, Writer. My problem is When i click on the Artist i need to display the list of artists in ASC order and When i click the same i need to display it in DESC order.

How is this possible to do ?

Thanks in Advance

Fero

Comment: Question is too vague. Provide source and a database schema. If you can't figure out how to do this, you should probably start with a tutorial on PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting the data from a database like MySQL, you want:

```
SELECT * FROM artists ORDER by artist_name DESC
```

Or, to sort them ascending:

```
SELECT * FROM artists ORDER by artist_name ASC
```

Or, you could do it in JavaScript (e.g. [this tutorial](http://rickyrosario.com/blog/sorting-dropdown-select-options-using-jquery)).

Without more details of how you're getting the data, it's a bit hard to help you more.